# Unmask gitolite version 3 on Gentoo

Tags: installation, gitolite, gentoo

I've tried to install gitolite v2, but couldn't setup it because of horrible strange bugs/errors.
Now I want to try gitolite v3 on Gentoo. I've added this line in

```
/etc/portage/package.unmask: =dev-vcs/gitolite-3*
```

As it is the same as in

```
/usr/portage/profiles/package.mask.
```

But when I type:

```
emerge -s gitolite or emerge -p gitolite
```

I couldn't find version 3, only version 2.
What am I doing wrong? How to correctly unmask this package? Should I change /usr/portage/profiles/package.mask?

**Solution:**
My colleague helped me.

```
echo '>=dev-vcs/gitolite-3.03 ~x86' >> /etc/portage/package.keywords
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most foolproof and convenient method I have found to unmask a specific ebuild is to let emerge do the unmasking for me:

```
sudo emerge =dev-vcs/gitolite-3.2 --autounmask-write
```

This generates the same lines that are recommended if you try emerging straight up ("The following *keyword changes* are necessary to proceed"), but takes the extra step of adding them to packages.keywords for you.

Since you said that you've "tried to install gitolite v2, but couldn't setup it because of horrible strange bugs/errors," you might also want to look at `=dev-vcs/gitolite-gentoo-2.3.1`, since that appears to be a fork of gitolite created specifically for Gentoo.

Comment: Yes, it's very useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend *not* using a package here.

Simply clone the GitHub Gitolite repo (which, by default, shows 'g3' or GitoliteV3 in `master`), and install it locally in any path you home (usually, `$HOME/bin`, with `$HOME` being the homedir of a dedicated gitolite admin account)

You can find a script automating the installation process here: [`install_or_update_gitolite.sh`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh).

Comment: As I know Gentoo Team strictly do not recommend using another method of installing software then emerge. Also, in general, it is difficult to uninstall software from Gentoo by this way as no dependencies, etc. Gitolite v3 was mask as it is completely new system,  which is very different from v2 - that is why update from v2 to v3 difficult/impossible. But as new system it is stable/good enough (as was in changelog, I haven't tested it yet). Here is changelog and the reason of masking: http://gentoobrowse.randomdan.homeip.net/package/dev-vcs/gitolite

Comment: @Mephi_stofel ok, my context is different, but in your case, your method is the way to go.